# Pin mounts horizontal pin rows

Tags: mount

I have a device (laser diode), rectangular, with pin rows of 7 pins in horizontal rows, spacing 2.54 mm, on the longer sides. Now I am looking for a mounting possibility to make mounting for the diode as easy as possible, while retaining the possibility of removing it without damage. Is there something I can use for mounting the device on a PCB with the properties mentioned above?

Image of the device: [image]

Comment: What about a DIL IC socket? If the row spacing is wrong cut the socket into 2 rows and mount the row separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two obvious options come to mind:

Bend the pins down at 90°.  Now you have a DIP (dual inline package).  If you're lucky, the spacing between the two rows of pins matches a common DIP spacing, or depending on how you bend the pins can be arranged to match a common spacing, like 600 mils.

If not, then two SIP (single in line package) sockets should work since you can mount them on the PCB at whatever spacing you want.  In a pinch, you might be able to saw or break a DIP socket to make two SIP sockets.

Bend the leads down to a little below the level of the bottom of the package, then continue them straight out from the package.  Now you have a SMD (surface mount device).  Just solder the pins down on pads normally.

These are much easier to unsolder than thru hole.

Comment: DIP/SIP sounds as a great idea, thanks! But I have to separate it, after the package itself is already at 13 mm width...

Comment: @arc: A 600 mil DIP socket might work then.

Comment: With those screw holes visible on the diode, it looks as though it almost wants to have a cut-out made of the PCB, it's leads soldered to the PCB, and mounting screws heat-sinking it to the enclosure. Couldn't find any datasheet for it.